# how to run php code multiple times with button click?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a block of php code for a form which have a select field that fetches its options from database. what I want to do is, generate that form multiple times by clicking a add button. Can anyone suggest how to do this task, Even conceptual suggestions or directions will also be helpful.

Comment: No code, no help. What about `for` loop by the way?

Comment: Probably AJAX, hard to say though. You could just do it with multi `form` submissions.

Comment: If I understand, You want to change the form when clicking on the form depending on the value of the select. All I can say is, Javascript can be handy. Not enough information to help you further.

Comment: Users on StackOverflow will help you, after you help yourself.  Take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour.  Do some research: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527.
Learn how to post good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  And http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var html = "<input type='text'><br>";

$(document).on("click", "#sel", function(){
 $("#myForm").append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="sel" value="Add input field">

<form id="myForm">
</form>
```

The code snippet above may help.

It you need the help of the `PHP` as well, use `AJAX`.

Comment: I'd probably do `<intput type="button" id="sel" value="Add input field(s)">`, the `1` or `2` isn't really related to what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Updated the snippet.